# Understanding IServiceProvider and QueryService

Tags: shell, winapi, service, interface, com

Can anyone explain the idea behind `IServiceProvider` and `QueryService`?  I don't understand what a service is and how it differs from another type of object or interface.  I've seen little explanation--mainly some remarks [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/cc678965(v=vs.85)) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa770042(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#iserviceprovider) on MSDN, but I don't understand them. Why would you have `IServiceProvider` and `QueryService` instead of just having some sort of "GetAnotherObject" method?  Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: No one can accuse Microsoft of not sufficiently re-inventing the wheel...

Comment: `IServiceProvider` is just a generic way to obtain one COM object from another; similar to how `IUnknown::QueryInterface` is a generic way to obtain one interface implemented by the object from another. Which "services" (other objects) are available from a given object would be described in its documentation; it's not otherwise discoverable (well, except by guessing and trying, I suppose).

Comment: Having `GetAnotherObject` method instead would mean that, if you later need a way to provide a third object, a new method `GetThirdObject` would need to be invented and added to the interface; but COM interfaces are immutable, evolution is difficult. So, instead of `GetAnotherObject`, `GetThirdObject`, `GetFourthObject` and so on, it's best to add a parameterized `GetObjectByID(SomeObjectID)` method. Et voila, you arrive at `IServiceProvider::QueryService`, which is just such a method.

Comment: QueryInterface has strong requirements, read the remarks here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-queryinterface(refiid_void) . QueryService is also a generic "query something" interface but has no specific requirements. Note that the SID argument and the IID argument are often equal.

Comment: `IServiceProvider::QueryService` is almost the same as `IUnknown::QueryInterface` with the difference that you don't expect implementation on the same object, with same lifetime and reference counter.

Comment: So then there's no real difference between a "service" and a class?

Comment: There is no concept of a *"class"* in COM. Functionality is exposed as an interface, encompassing a set of functions. A service is a set of one or more interfaces. The implementation is transparent and at the discretion of the implementer. An implementer can choose any scheme so long as it meets the requirements of the protocol. That includes an implementation using C, that has no notion of a class at all.