# What's the relationship between SID_STopLevelBrowser and IWebBrowser2?

Tags: shell, winapi, interface, com, iwebbrowser2

In Raymond's [demonstration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040720-00/?p=38393) of how to hop around some shell objects, he first obtains an `IWebBrowser2` (or technically `IWebBrowserApp`), and then uses `QueryService` to get to `SID_STopLevelBrowser`. I was wondering if anyone can explain conceptually what those two things are and how they're related.  Is one inside the other within an Explorer window?  Thanks for any info.

Comment: Now you should now what IServiceProvider is for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59432866/understanding-iserviceprovider-and-queryservice and SID_STopLevelBrowser is (ancient knowledge) documented in an old Microsoft KB article (Q257717 "How To Retrieve the Top-Level IWebBrowser2 Interface from an ActiveX Control") that's been gone now, but you can find on wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20140417005545/https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257717

Comment: So there are actually two `IWebBrowser2`s? I don't understand.  Can you perhaps explain the hierarchy of objects?  Also it seems that `SID_STopLevelBrowser` is misleading, because the article suggests that `IWebBrowser2` is on a higher level.  Is that correct?

Comment: Any COM interface can be implemented by any class, event if it's not specifically documented (and it's getting worse... we have to use wayback machine). SID_STopLevelBrowser  ensures you get the top level one, from any one in the hierarchy. There's basically no more documentation.

Comment: This is about 1996, Microsoft was caught somewhat by surprise by the Internet revolution.  Trying to catch up, they tried to make the distinction between Explorer and a browser disappear.  That did not turn out well, they're kinda stuck with maintaining compatibility for old programs.  They can only delete the docs to discourage anybody from still using it.  Do feel free to be discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

`SID_STopLevelBrowser` is just a GUID telling `QueryService` (in this case) which hierarchy object you are interested in. What you are really asking about is; what is the difference between `IWebBrowser` and `IShellBrowser`.

`IWebBrowser` is a Internet Explorer object but when Explorer.exe gained web support in Win98/IE4, a plain Explorer.exe also gained the ability to host web pages (this ability was disabled/deprecated in Vista). The top level `(SID_STopLevelBrowser`) [`IShellBrowser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellbrowser) on the other hand is the classic "host" object that hosts `IShellView` (the file list in all versions of Explorer):

> Implemented by hosts of Shell views (objects that implement IShellView). Exposes methods that provide services for the view it is hosting and other objects that run in the context of the Explorer window.

Users of Windows 95 could choose to install IE4 without the shell update and on those systems there is full separation between Explorer and Internet Explorer.

Raymond asks for this other browser object because he needs to call `IShellBrowser::QueryActiveShellView` to gain access to the shell view and the world of `IShellFolder`s and PIDLs.

You can think of `IShellBrowser` as the host/container of `IWebBrowser` and/or `IShellView` but keep in mind that `IShellView` can be implemented by 3rd-parties when you are in special namespace folders and `IShellBrowser` can be implemented by 3rd-party file explorer applications so you can't really say that `IWebBrowser` and the other parts of a Explorer window are tightly connected.

When `QueryService` does not know the service you are asking for, it is allowed to ask its client-site/host/"parent"/"child". If you want to get the "main" view instance you ask for `SID_STopLevelBrowser`. Similarly, you can ask the top level browser for [`SID_SShellBrowser` to get the current tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752126(v=vs.85)) in IE7+.